# Can router.push be used from Redux thunk? Is it a good practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-thunk

I have this anchor element:

```js
<a
  className="btn btn-sm btn-circle"
  href={`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENVIRONMENT == "prod"
      ? "https://tikex.com"
      : "https://tikex-staging.com"
  }/share/${organizationSlug}/${postId}&quote=${postSurveySchemaDTO?.caption}`}
  onClick={(e) => {
    dispatch(
      createShare({
        tempUserId: "e3445c3b-5513-4ede-8229-d258ed4418ae",
        postId,
      })
    );
  }}
>
  Megosztom
</a>
```

I tested many times, maybe one time only but seem than onclick and networking was not triggered in that case, 99% ok. Is it better if I trigger navigation also from `onClick` after networking was done?

Can I trigger `router.push()` from `reducer` / `thunk`?

Like this?

```js
export const createShare = createAsyncThunk(
    `${namespace}/createShare`,
    async (props: any, { dispatch }) => {
        const { data } = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'share',
            data: props,
            headers: { crossDomain: true },
        }).then((res) => {
            router.push(`http://...`)
            return res
        })
        return data
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a race condition.

1. the the `<a>` is trying to navigate the browser away to the `href`
2. `onClick` has a `dispatch(createShare(...))` trigger

I would suggest preventing the default `<a>` event and manually choreograph the two separate events -

```js
onClick(e => {
  e.preventDefault() // stop the browser from trying to navigate away
  dispatch(
    createShare({
      ...
      thenNavigateTo: e.target.href // or whatever
    })
  )
}
```

If you need `router` to navigate, you can pass a thunk to the dispatched action -

```js
onClick(e => {
  e.preventDefault() // stop the browser from trying to navigate away
  dispatch(
    createShare({
      ...
      andThen: _ => router.push(e.target.href) // or whatever
    })
  )
}
```